# Issue with resizing fields of form under symfony 3

Tags: php, css, symfony

I have a problem with resizing the fields I've generated with symfony, my fields take the whole width of the page. Here is my code:

Controller :

```
$user= new User();
        $form=$this->CreateFormBuilder($user)
            ->add("firstName",TextType::class)
            ->add("lastName",TextType::class)
            ->add("login",TextType::class)
            ->add("password",PasswordType::class)
            ->add("tel",TextType::class)
            ->add("email",TextType::class)
            ->add("address",TextType::class)
            ->add("send",SubmitType::class)
            -> getForm();
        $form->handleRequest($req);
        if($form->isValid())
        {
            $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($user);
            $em->flush();
        }

        return $this->render('eplateformeBundle:Default:register.html.twig',['form'=>$form->createView()]);
```

The view :

```
<div class="well">
      {{ form_start(form ) }}
      {{ form_errors(form) }}
      {{ form_row(form.firstName) }}
      {{ form_row(form.lastName) }}
      {{ form_row(form.login) }}
      {{ form_row(form.password) }}
      {{ form_row(form.tel) }}
      {{ form_row(form.email) }}
      {{ form_row(form.address) }}
      {{ form_widget(form.send, {'attr': {'class': 'btn btn-primary'}}) }}
      {{ form_rest(form) }}
      {{ form_end(form) }}
</div>
```

Comment: You could add "<br/>" after each form_row. Not sure if that would work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can transfer own class to inputs fields like this:

```
<div class="well">
      {{ form_start(form ) }}
      {{ form_errors(form) }}
      {{ form_row(form.firstName,{'attr':{'class':'your own class''}}) }}
      {{ form_row(form.lastName,{'attr':{'class':'your own class''}}) }}
      {{ form_row(form.login,{'attr':{'class':'your own class''}}) }}
      {{ form_row(form.password,{'attr':{'class':'your own class''}}) }}
      {{ form_row(form.tel,{'attr':{'class':'your own class''}}) }}
      {{ form_row(form.email,{'attr':{'class':'your own class''}}) }}
      {{ form_row(form.address,{'attr':{'class':'your own class''}}) }}
      {{ form_widget(form.send, {'attr': {'class': 'btn btn-primary'}}) }}
      {{ form_rest(form) }}
      {{ form_end(form) }}
</div>
```

Comment: In fact it was a cache problem that prevented me to see the changes.After cleaning cache using php bin/console cache:clear every thing worked